# Post on Facebook wall without link?

Tags: ios, facebook

Is it posible to post on Facebook wall using FBDialogs without posting links? I only want to post text message without pics or links.

When I try

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"Message", @"name",
    @"Message", @"message",
    nil];

// Invoke the dialog
[self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

it posts empty post.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"Message", @"name",
    nil];

// Invoke the dialog
[self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

That is, do not pass in the message parameter and it will be filled with whatever the user inputs. Anyway it's against Facebook policy to pre-fill the message field.